# How to call a function when clicking on an image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I know it's easy to call a function with Tkinter buttons by using `command`, but it doesn't work the same way with images. My question is pretty simple I believe, how can I call a function by clicking on an image?

Here's the code. I want to click on `picture` and that will call the `make_newwindow` function.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def make_newwindow():
    global newwindow
    root.withdraw()
    newwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow.title('Nível da grama região 2')
    newwindow.geometry('580x520')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Nível da grama região 1')
root.geometry("580x520")
picture = PhotoImage(file="picture.png")
label0 = Label(root, image=picture, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
label0.place(x=62, y=205)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the simplest way to do it would be to attach the image to a `Button` instead of a `Label` widget, because then all you would need to do is specify a `command=` argument referencing the function you want to be called when it's clicked.

Here's what I mean:

```
import tkinter as tk

def make_newwindow():
    global newwindow

    raiz.withdraw()
    newwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow.title('Nível da grama região 2')
    newwindow.geometry('580x520')

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title('Nível da grama região 1')
raiz.geometry("580x520")

picture = tk.PhotoImage(file="picure.png")
btn0 = tk.Button(raiz, image=picture, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                 command=make_newwindow)
btn0.place(x=62, y=205)

raiz.mainloop()
```

If you really want to use a `Label` for some reason, you can call the universal [`bind()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190326025633id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html#bind) widget method to attach your function to mouse button-1 click [events](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408103842id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html).

To do that, change the code above so it creates a `Label` (like your code does), but also calls `bind()` as illustrated. Note how a callback function is being created dynamically via a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression. This is needed because your `make_newwindow()` doesn't accept any arguments. However `tkinter` event-handler callback functions are all passed an `event` argument (see [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)). Since it's not needed here, the argument is simply ignored and has been given the name `_` (the Python convention for such things).

```
...
picture = tk.PhotoImage(file="picure.png")
label0 = tk.Label(raiz, image=picture, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
label0.place(x=62, y=205)
label0.bind('<Button-1>', lambda *_: make_newwindow())  # Create and bind callback func.

raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?
Here's the complete code that works

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def make_newwindow(data):
    global newwindow
    root.withdraw()
    newwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow.title('Nível da grama região 2')
    newwindow.geometry('580x520')


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Nível da grama região 1')
root.geometry("580x520")
picture = PhotoImage(file="Capture001.png")
label0 = Label(root, image=picture, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
label0.place(x=62, y=205)


label0.pack()
label0.bind('<Button-1>', func=make_newwindow)


root.mainloop()
```

the `data` is the information about the even that occured

Comment: I'm receiving the following error. I'd appreciate if you could help me, I'm just starting to learn python. Thanks. The error is: TypeError: make_newwindow() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given...

Comment: There's no reason to call both `place` and `pack` on `label0`.